# Using identity to populate subject in <a href="mailto:&subject"

Tags: javascript, href

Is there a way to set ID to some field, and later to use that in < a href="mailto:&**subject**">, without using function?

For example:

```
<input id="abc" type="text"/>
<a href="mailto:someone@something.com&subject=abc(id)">
```

Basically, to be self populated, when I type in some text in the "Some input:" field.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible.  You need the Javascript to bind to something (such as onChange of `#abc`.  You don't have to use a defined function (you could use an anonymous function), but I don't believe you can do it all in the browser bar.

Comment: What do you mean by _"without using function?"_

Comment: You'd have to use JavaScript, but I'm with Spencer - not sure what you mean by that. A simple event listener on the input could update the `href` attribute accordingly.

Comment: Since I will have like 20 email buttons, and the subject of those emails will depend on whatever is written in one field. Per my knowledge, I would need to make 20 different functions for each email button. 
Or is there a way to make one email button function, and to use that one for all 20 email buttons in the template? 
I will attach the picture as well, to explain it a bit better